# Lasso model by glmnet package in small sample size

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet, lasso-regression

I want to create a lasso model, but I can't have a test set because I have a small sample size, so I want to use cross-validation to evaluate the model.
In other posts, I saw that functions like cv.glmnet and caret are used to make the lasso model. Now, my question is, should caret be used instead of cv.glmnet to get the confusion matrix for cross-validation in the case of small sample size? Or will cv.glmnet be used as inner CV for pick lambda and caret for outer CV? Knowing this question is important for me to make sure if I should use cv.glmnet or not.

```
data=read.xlsx("data.xlsx")

head(data)

dim(data)

summary(data)

# Set seed for reproducible random partitioning of data

set.seed(100)

x=as.matrix(data[,-1]) ; y= data[,1]

#fit lasso model for binomial outcome

Lasso.mod = glmnet(x, y, alpha=1,family="binomial", type.measure='deviance')

plot(Lasso.mod, xvar="lambda")

#best lambda

cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, type.measure='deviance',family="binomial",nfold=10)

plot(cv.out)

best.lambda <- cv.out$lambda.min

best.lambda
```